# Kendo variables in Command section in a grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have noticed that it is possible to have some kendo logic and variables inside a template in the columns sections.

This is an example from my column section template

```
  template: "#= myVariable#  #if(myBoolean) {# <img src='/images/myImage.png' /> #}#"
```

Please do note that myVariable and myBoolean are variables (fields) of each row of the grid. 
Unfortunately i tried the same under the command section in the template. I get the following error "ReferenceError: myVariable is not defined"

Is there any way to add variables in the command sections as it happens with the columns?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know using templates in `columns.command` is not even documented: although it works. And you can do things like:

```
columns   : [
    {
        command: {
            template : "# console.log('this', this); console.log('data', data); # toto"
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

or even like:

```
command: {
    template : function (arg) {
        console.log("this" ,this);
        console.log("arg", arg);
        console.log("data", data);
        return "toto";
    }
}
```

But what the template returns needs to be a `string` and in the console of your browser you will see that `this` is `window`, `arg` is the object `command` and `data` is an `array` containing grid data.

Although you can include extra arguments as:

```
command: {
    template : function (arg) {
        console.log("this" ,this);
        console.log("arg", arg);
        console.log("arg.a", arg.a);
        console.log("data", data);
        return "toto";
    },
    a: "extra argument"
}
```

Where I add an extra `a` argument that can be accessed via `arg.a` you still cannot get access to current row `data` since the element is still not inserted.

Instead of that what I do propose is doing something like:

```
columns   : [
    {
        title: " ",
        template: "#= myVariable#  #if(myBoolean) {# <img src='/images/myImage.png' /> #}#"
    },
    ...
]
```

You don't need to have it as command, right? Why do you need it as command?